# Locate xcodeproj in terminal

Tags: iphone, terminal

How can i locate my project in terminal which i created in xcode?

How can i add or install Submodules of Sharekit to my project?

I am trying to locate my project created in Xcode.

When i type in locate abc.xcodeproj

it gives this warning

**WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:
  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.**

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locate` is somewhat obsolete. Use Spotlight instead:

```
$ mdfind abc.xcodeproj
```